# How can I split a long HTML table using print-CSS, so that the split in the table on the first page leaves space for a div at the bottom of the page?

Tags: css, firefox, media-queries, print-css

I have a mutli-page document that is displayed in a browser window. The document is a long table and a legend.

I want the table to stop printing some 300 pixels before the bottom of the page, then print the legend, and then continue printing the table on the second page.

[image]

The red line indicates where I want the table to break.

How ?

**What I have so far:**

Currently I was able to print the legend at the bottom of the first page, using CSS below:

```
    @media print {
        #legend {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    }
```

But my table is printing right over the legend div, superimposing itself over the legend.

What I need is for the table div to stop printing before the legend div, then print the legend div, then continue the table on the next page.

**Hack #1**

I could force a page break on a certain row, by using

```
<style>
.page-break-tr {
    page-break-after: always;
}            
</style>

<!-- row i.e. 15, which is controlled by a loop in the code -->
<tr class="page-break-tr"> 

<!-- normal row -->
<tr>
```

This kinda works but not exactly great, since it's hardcoded.  Table data changes, moving table border up and down.

I would like to ideally find a better way to handle these.